# error C2664: in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
for (int v = 0; v <= WordChosen.length();v++)
{
    if(Letter == WordChosen[v])
    {
        WordChosenDuplicate.replace(v,1,Letter);
    }
}
```

I get this error

> "Error    4   error C2664:
>   'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>
>   &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::replace(__w64
>   unsigned int,__w64 unsigned int,const
>   std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>
>   &)' : cannot convert parameter 3 from
>   'char' to 'const
>   std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>
>   &'    c:\documents and settings\main\my
>   documents\uni\2nd
>   year\tp2\hangman\hangman\hangman.cpp  147
>   "

I only got the error after putting this line in

```
WordChosenDuplicate.replace(v,1,Letter);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or

```
WordChosenDuplicate.replace(v,1,std::string(Letter, 1));
```

Answer (score 3):

The `std::string::replace()` function's parameters are incorrect or you need to invoke a different overload of `replace`. Something like:

```
 WordChosenDuplicate.replace(v, // substring begining at index v
                             1, // of length 1
                             1, // replace by 1 copy of
                             Letter); // character Letter
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to achieve? The version of `replace` that you are trying to call doesn't exist – as the compiler is telling you. Which of [these versions](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/replace) do you mean?

Comment: Sorry i was following this book and they say "str1.replace(m,n,str2) and Paramenters m and n are of type string::size_type"

Comment: Your third argument has to be of type `string`, though (not `char`).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that WordChosenDuplicate is a std::string, in which case the 3rd parameter in the replace() method should be another std::string or a c-style const char*. You are trying to pass a single char instead ("Letter"). The error is saying that there is no version of replace() that takes a char as the 3rd parameter.